# How to get image from youtube using Jsoup?

Tags: java, android, youtube, jsoup, metadata

I want when the user clicks the icon "Add Video" button, create a dialog in which he can insert a link, which he copied.

After that, pressing the "ok" button will load the page that the user entered (from youtube) and from there take a video ID. Will store everything about this element `<meta itemprop =" videoId "content =" lWHKaK7Ql3k ">`.

Search for ID can be advised by means JSOUP library, but I found examples of [**html**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623302/get-meta-data-of-image-android). Once we obtain the ID, we try to get a picture.

Prompt please as it is possible to generate an image with added video and add it to the list, as shown in the screenshot.
[image]
My code with dialog:

```
private void showAddVideoDialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    builder.setTitle("Add video");
    View viewInflated = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_layout_add_video, (ViewGroup) getView(), false);
    final EditText input = (EditText) viewInflated.findViewById(R.id.edt_videoUrl);
    builder.setView(viewInflated);

    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            m_Text = input.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ОК", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Отмена", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

Non-sarcastic/non-condescending responses are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The community appreciates sincere responses only. You need not worry about that.

Comment: If you get a youtube link e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XpnKHJAok8 then you already got the id: `4XpnKHJAok8` and can retrieve an image using https://i.ytimg.com/vi/[videoID]/hqdefault.jpg (https://i.ytimg.com/vi/4XpnKHJAok8/hqdefault.jpg)

Comment: @F.Klein I don't really know where/and how I should to get link and id.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903754/input-text-dialog-android Currently your question is too broad (it's more ore less: write me an app), try to be more specific or break the question down into multiple questions within the scope of stackoverflow's definition of fitting topics (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @F.Klein thanks, but i haven't problem to create dialog. I don't understand how to work with metadata(check link/get id)

Answer (score 4):

> *In the following answer, I assume that the user has copied a youtube URL (`youtubeUrl`) into your application input field.*

#### Sample code

```
String youtubeUrl = ...

// Extract video ID
Document videoPage = Jsoup.connect(youtubeUrl).get();

Element videoIdMeta = videoPage.select("div[itemtype=http://schema.org/VideoObject] meta[itemprop=videoId]").first();
if (videoIdMeta == null) {
    // Unable to determine videoId ...
} else {
    String videoId = videoIdMeta.attr("content");

    // Fetch video image
    String videoImageUrl = String.format("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/%s/hqdefault.jpg", videoId);
    Connection.Response response = Jsoup //
        .connect(videoImageUrl) //
        .ignoreContentType(true) // Needed for fetching image
        .execute();

    // Load image for later use
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(response.bodyAsBytes()));
}
```

#### See also

- [How to get an image with Jsoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34491304/363573)
- [How to get youtube video id with Jsoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39742707/363573)
- [Android: Load image from url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5776903/363573)
- [BitmapFactory javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html)

Comment: super response, thanks! But can ask one more quick question, how to combine it with my dialogue?

Comment: @vadimmorozov Can you please rephrase your question?

Comment: Yes of course, I'll try. I want to add your solution to my fragment. So when user inserting a link to my dialog and click OK, run your solution.

Comment: @VadimMorozov Put the solution in a method then call the method.

Comment: Whether it is possible to implement without connection libraries(jsoup)?

Answer (score 1):

use this URL to get image relate to youtube id https://i.ytimg.com/vi/{ID}/hqdefault.jpg

where ID is your youtube id